# git clean -ndX doesn't remove directory

Tags: git

With `.gitignore`:

`foo/`

and a git repository of:

```
./quux
./quux/foo
./quux/foo/bar
./quux/foo/bar/baz
```

As `foo` is ignored, git assumes working directory is clean:

```
% git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

The `git clean -ndx` prints:

```
% git clean -ndx
Would remove quux/
```

But `git clean -ndX` doesn't print anything. I would expect it to remove `quux/` as well.

Is this a bug or a some gitignore feature I don’t get?
If I add some file to `quux` and commit it. Than git clean will try to remove `quux/foo/` as expected.

My git is pretty new: `git version 1.8.3.4`.

Comment: Is `./quux/foo/bar/baz` a file or directory? Are any other files in your repository?

Comment: `baz` is a file. No other files. Files outside `quux/` doesn't affect the behaviour in any way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ git init .
$ echo foo/ >.gitignore
$ git add .;git commit -am ignore
$ mkdir -p foo/bar bar/foo
$ touch foo/bar/1 bar/foo/1
$ git clean -ndx
Would remove bar/
Would remove foo/
$ git clean -ndX
Would remove foo/
$
```

`git help clean` says:

```
   -X
       Remove only files ignored by Git. This may be useful to rebuild
       everything from scratch, but keep manually created files.
```

This means it will not delete manual created stuff, unless it is explicitly ignored.

In this case the `bar` directory is manually created and not explicitly ignored, hence it will not be deleted.

The same is true for your `quux` directory.

To "fix" this you need to add the `bar` directory under control of git by adding a file:

```
$ touch bar/x
$ git add bar/x
$ git commit -am add\ x
$ git clean -ndX
Would remove bar/foo/
Would remove foo/
$
```

Comment: So `foo/` in the root of working directory is explicitly ignore, but `bar/foo/` is just implicitly, thus not removed?
The follow up question: how to git clean so that implicitly ignored files are also removed?

This is feels somehow unlogical, as if there is any file in `bar/` tracked by git, than `bar/foo/` will be removed.

Comment: Almost. `bar` is manually created, therefore git will not touch anything inside. After adding `bar` to source control, the directory is no longer considered manual and git will do as you expect it.

Comment: But what about `git status`, it's shows that working directory is clean, while it doesn't. IMHO there's mismatch in definition of "clean", between `git clean` and `git status`

Comment: Git normally only cares about files. You cannot track empty directories. Therefore `git status` does not find any new files and reports it as clean. `git clean` then sees a directory it does not know about (because it contains no git managed files), and therefore states it is created manually, hence it does not care what is inside.