# How can I git clean manually created files

Tags: git

Is it possible (without doing a git clone again) to bring by repo to a "clean" state, in that also files, which are manually created, are removed?

I have a directory which is gitignored:

```
# .gitignore
mydir/
```

The directory mydir has been manually created and contains files. When I do a

```
git clean -X -f .
```

in the base directory of my repo, mydir is not removed. This seems to be in concordance with the documentation, as we can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19905016/git-clean-ndx-doesnt-remove-directory).

My question is now: What would be the best way of cleaning my repo? I could `rm -rf` my repo and then run `git clone`, but maybe there is a "better" way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the `-d` flag

> -d
>
> Remove untracked directories in addition to untracked files. If an untracked directory is managed by a different Git repository, it is
>   not removed by default. Use -f option twice if you really want to
>   remove such a directory.

and the `-x` flag

> -x
>
> Don’t use the standard ignore rules read from .gitignore (per directory) and $GIT_DIR/info/exclude, but do still use the ignore
>   rules given with -e options. This allows removing all untracked files,
>   including build products. This can be used (possibly in conjunction
>   with git reset) to create a pristine working directory to test a clean
>   build.

When you do a `$ git clean -xdf` using `-x` and `-d` together it will also remove untracked/ignored **d**irectories

Also see http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean